# Using HttpURLConnection on Android

Tags: android, webserver, httpurlconnection

I am trying to connect a web server I have running in my android App however for some reason it's failing.

I can connect to the webpage normally and using my phone's browser, I can also use the below code to connect to google but for some reason my code will not connect to my web server. If I host the server on port 80 I get error code 503 every time, if I host it on 8080 (which is preferable) I get a timeout exception which is below.

```
03-05 20:12:22.432: WARN/System.err(29254): java.net.SocketException: The operation timed out
03-05 20:12:22.602: WARN/System.err(29254):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.connectSocketImpl(Native Method)
03-05 20:12:22.602: WARN/System.err(29254):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.connect(OSNetworkSystem.java:125)
03-05 20:12:22.602: WARN/System.err(29254):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:227)
03-05 20:12:22.612: WARN/System.err(29254):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:521)
03-05 20:12:22.612: WARN/System.err(29254):     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:1019)
03-05 20:12:22.612: WARN/System.err(29254):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:67)
03-05 20:12:22.612: WARN/System.err(29254):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnectionManager$ConnectionPool.getHttpConnection(HttpConnectionManager.java:151)
03-05 20:12:22.612: WARN/System.err(29254):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnectionManager.getConnection(HttpConnectionManager.java:73)
03-05 20:12:22.612: WARN/System.err(29254):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getHTTPConnection(HttpURLConnection.java:826)
03-05 20:12:22.612: WARN/System.err(29254):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:812)
03-05 20:12:22.612: WARN/System.err(29254):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:1275)
03-05 20:12:22.612: WARN/System.err(29254):     at com.project.library.remailer.ServerSelect.downloadDirectory(ServerSelect.java:84)
03-05 20:12:22.622: WARN/System.err(29254):     at com.project.main.NewMessage$3$1$1.run(NewMessage.java:156)
```

The code is:

```
try {
    URL url = new URL(directoryLocation);
    HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url
            .openConnection();

    // The line below is where the exception is called
    int response = httpURLConnection.getResponseCode();                 
    if (response == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {


        // Response successful
    InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();

    // Parse it line by line
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    String temp;
    while ((temp = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        // Parsing of data here
    }
       } else {
            Log.e("SAMES", "INCORRECT RETURN CODE: " + response);
       }
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

When I try the code in the link suggested by CommonsWare for port 8080 I get the same error as before, the timeout exception. For port 80 I get the following exception, both of these errors occur on the url.openStream().

Port 80 exception:

```
03-06 11:53:53.296: WARN/System.err(639): java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://64.197.194.165:80/path
03-06 11:53:53.376: WARN/System.err(639):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1064)
03-06 11:53:53.376: WARN/System.err(639):     at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:674)
03-06 11:53:53.376: WARN/System.err(639):     at com.project.library.remailer.ServerSelect.downloadDirectory(ServerSelect.java:118)
03-06 11:53:53.376: WARN/System.err(639):     at com.project.main.NewMessage$3$1$1.run(NewMessage.java:156)
```

I also tried using the following code:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(directoryLocation);
        try
        {
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
            String line;
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                Log.e("SAMES", line);
        }

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

However that has resulted in the same timeout error for port 8080, which occurs when client.execute(response) is called.

For port 80 I get a webpage which says that it couldn't connect, which alot of HTML editing, however the main thing it says on the page is:

> 03-06 13:10:23.576: ERROR/SAMES(1267): The Web Server may be down, too busy, or experiencing other problems preventing it from responding to requests. You may wish to try again at a later time.

Comment: I can also provide the webserver code if needed.

I also have added internet to the manifest so that is not the problem

Comment: I had the same exact exception happening at my end.
Though the bug I found was a null value was being set for a request-header property of HttpURLConnection.
Maybe this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

Various notes:

- You don't indicate where the timeout occurred.
- You might try [this example](http://exampledepot.com/egs/java.net/ReadFromURL.html), which uses URL differently than you are.
- Your error code 503 on port 80 should result in some error information on your server that might be useful.
- Are there any proxy servers or other things between your phone and the Web server?
- Have you tried with both WiFi and 3G?
- You might try switching to HttpClient and see if you get better results or perhaps a better error message.

Comment: Appended the above code with my response for trying the new code.                              
On the web server it's meant to print a response when a connection comes through, however it doesn't say anyone is connecting for any of the above attempts.                       
I will test HttpClient in a bit and get back with the results from that.                       
Also I only have access to 3G atm and testing on Wifi will prove to be difficult.                              
As far as I know there are no proxy servers in between my phone and the webserver either.

Comment: Your carrier may well have proxy servers between your phone and your server. Conceivably, they may not be supporting port 8080, though I would find that somewhat unusual. Particularly for your port 80 test, see if your server actually registers a hit. FWIW, I would recommend the ResponseHandler pattern for text responses with HttpClient.

Comment: I don't think there is a proxy in the way as when I use the phone's normal browser I can access the web page regardless of the port. So there must be something wrong with my code.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is too complex (in my opinion) to address it fully, so I'd like to share my findings on a problem I've been having recently, which caused exactly what you described in your comment:

```
// The line below is where the exception is called
int response = httpURLConnection.getResponseCode();
```

That same piece of code caused `IOException` in one of my classes - every time, on every valid `URL`, so it was clear the problem was in the code - which looked the same as yours - simple, no headers set, nothing above tutorial-like examples. I then noticed that every example I've seen was not even calling `URLConnection.connect()` method - so I thought: when does the actual connection occur? What does standard `HttpURLConnection` use pattern look like?

Unfortunately, the documentation is scarce on that topic. So I've done some googling and found this blog post: **[HttpURLConnection's Dark Secrets - by Tim Bray](http://www.tbray.org/ongoing/When/201x/2012/01/17/HttpURLConnection)** which was invaluable in writing more complex `HttpURLConnection` use-ceses. It also provided an answer to my problem - let me quote relevant lines:

```
// this opens a connection, then sends GET & headers 
in = conn.getInputStream(); 

// can't get status before getInputStream.  If you try, you'll
//  get a nasty exception.
http_status = conn.getResponseCode();

// better check it first
if (http_status / 100 != 2) {
   // redirects, server errors, lions and tigers and bears! Oh my!
}
```

See the 1st and 2nd comment? Well, that makes a lot of sense when you know that actual network connection is initiated by `HttpURLConnection.getInputStream()` (`HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream()` if you're sending any content to the server). Placing invocation of `getResponseCode()` *after* `getInputStream()` fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you try calling `httpURLConnection.connect()` after calling `url.openConnection()`?

Comment: I tried this and here are the results.

When I try to connect to port 80 on the server I get to the getResponse90 function call then the 503 error.

When I try with port 8080 I get the Timeout exception about at the connect() function call

Answer (score -2):

Only an app with root permissions can open ports below 1024 - that's the issue with port 80.

Comment: That's for servers. He's not writing a server. Else that would have mean every app has root permissions, which is certainly not the case.